# How to pass cell value as parameter in google apps script function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm in need of some help with the final part of my code. I'm working with an API to get the name of the street and city from the government database and i use the Zip code and house number as input. The API i have working, but the final step is to pass cell values (Zip code, house number) as parameters into my formula. I cannot seem to get this working.

Here is my code:

```
function postHuisNaarStraat (ref1, ref2){
  
  var PCCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref1).getValue();
  var HNCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref2).getValue();
  
  var postcode = "filters[postcode]=" + PCCell;
  var huisnummer = "filters[huisnummer]=" + HNCell;
  
  var API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var url = "https://api.overheid.io/bag?" + postcode + "&" + huisnummer;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url,
    {
      "headers":{
        "ovio-api-key":API_KEY,
        "Accept":"application/hal+json",
        "Content-Type":"application/json"   
      }
    }
  );
  
  // parse JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  
  // Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(data["_embedded"]["adres"][0]["openbareruimte"]);
  
  
}
```

Please help me get the data from my cells (postcode, housenumber) and add their respective value in my formula.

Here is what i want to do but cant get working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  var PCCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref1).getValue();
  var HNCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(ref2).getValue();
```

by

```
  var PCCell = ref1;
  var HNCell = ref2;
```

or even better (as this will make your code shorter), instead of  `ref1` and `ref2` as function argument names use `PCCell` and `HNCell`, respectivelly.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets